# showDialog doesn't show custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I just defined a dialog as android site suggest, but it does not show on button click, some code scracht (I get no errors):
    static final int DIALOG_A = 1;
    static final int DIALOG_B = 2;
    TextView textX;

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, String text) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(decrytedText);
    Log.v("DialogTest", "  onCreateDialog(): +++ START +++");

    switch(id) 
    {
        case DIALOG_A:
            dialog.setTitle(this.getString(R.string.dialog_title_wrong_key));
            break;
        case DIALOG_B:
            dialog.setTitle(this.getString(R.string.dialog_title_ok_key));
            break;
    }
    return dialog;
}

 somebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    Object butts[] = (Object []) v.getTag();

                    try 
                    {
                        Log.v("DialogTest", " try");
                        String decrypted ="OK GO";
                        textX.setText(decrypted);
                        showDialog(DIALOG_A);
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        Log.v("DialogTest", "catch");
                        textX.setText(R.string.dialog_no_wrong_key);
                        showDialog(DIALOG_B);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: edit your post with showDialog() method code

Comment: Whats the constant DIALOG_DECRYPT_TEXT indicating?

Comment: I just copied from another code, I intend this as general example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there should be signature of  onCreateDialog like this as [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int%29)

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)

// or

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args)
```

[link1](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDialogs/article.html)

Comment: Thank you, the @Override forgoten (but that I do not know I have to put) was actually the problem